# Showing that every subgroup of a factor group $G/N$ has the form $H/N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$.
>
> Use the property that for a homomorphism $\phi$ from $G$ to $\bar{G}$ where $\bar{H}$
>
> $\phi^{-1}\left ( \bar{H} \right )=\left \{ x \in G: \phi\left ( x \right ) \in \bar{H}\right \}$ is a subgroup of $\bar{G}$ is a subgroup of G.

Prove that every subgroup of $G/N$ has the form $H/N$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I would appreciate hints.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Does normal subgroups being kernel of some homomorphism comes into play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S$ be a subgroup of $G/N$ and let $S'=\{g\in G\,|\,gN\in S\}$. Then $S'$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $S=S'/N$.

Comment: Does it utilise the required property?

Comment: @Mathematicing Sure. If $\phi$ is the projection of $G$ onto $G/N$, then $S'=\phi^{-1}(S)$.

Comment: Thanks!@jose carlos santos