# Subgroup of factor/quotient group $G/N$ is of form $H/N$ for $N \subseteq H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

From Lee's *Abstract Algebra*, Theorem 4.8 (proof as exercise for the reader):

> Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup. Then the subgroups of
>   $G/N$ are precisely of the form $H/N$, where $N \leq H \leq G$.

Note that $H \leq G$ means "$H$ is a subgroup of $G$."

---

This question begins exactly the same way as [Showing that every subgroup of a factor group $G/N$ has the form $H/N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355740/showing-that-every-subgroup-of-a-factor-group-g-n-has-the-form-h-n), but without using homomorphisms. To do this:

Let $J \subseteq G/N=\{aN : a \in G\}$, so $J=\{bN : b \in H \subseteq G \}$. So any subset $J$ of $G/N$ is of the form $J=H/N$ for $H \subseteq G$.

Now suppose that $J \leq G/N$, so $J$ is a group of the form $H/N$. Thus $eN \in J$, [$bN \in J \implies b^{-1}N \in J$], and [$b_1N,b_2N \in J \implies b_1 b_2 N=b_3N \in J$]. In other words, $e\in H$, $H$ contains inverses, and $H$ is closed under $G$'s binary operation. So any subgroup $J$ of $G/N$ is of the form $J=H/N$ for $H \leq G$.

**Now how do I show that $N \subseteq H$ to complete the proof?**

---

Here's some of my failed attempt: Let $n \in N$ and $H/N \leq G/N$, we must show that $n \in H$. Suppose  that $n \notin H \leq G$, so $n^{-1} \notin H$. Then the cosets $nN=Nn$ and $n^{-1}N=Nn^{-1}$ are not in the group $H/N$  ... stuck.

EDIT: I notice that $nN=N=eN$, so the set $nN$ is certainly in $H/N$, but I don't think this proves $n$ must be in $H$. Also, this seems to be part of the "correspondence theorem for groups," but I am having trouble understanding the proofwiki (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Correspondence_Theorem_%28Group_Theory%29) and wonder if there's an easier way to show only the part that $N \subseteq H$.

Comment: If $K$ is an arbitrary subgroup of $G$ (not necessarily containing $N$), and $J$ is the set of cosets of the form $kN$ where $k \in K$, then you can check that $J = KN/N$. Since $N \leq KN$, you can let $H = KN$. Note that if $N$ is already contained in $K$, then $KN=K$ and you can take $H=K$.

Comment: I want to prove that whenever $H/N \leq G/N$ for $H \leq G$, we must have $N \subseteq H$. I see this is true if we choose $H=KN$, but how do we know $H$ must be equal to $KN$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proofwiki proof goes as follows: let $J$ be a subgroup of $G/N$, so $J$ is some set of cosets of $N$. Define $\beta(J)=\{g \in G \mid gN \in J \} \subseteq G$; notice that one way of expressing $J$ is $J = \beta(J) / N$. And $J$ is a group, so $nN=N=eN \in J$, so $N \subseteq \beta(J) \subseteq G$. To complete the proof, show that $\beta(J)$ is a group, which I already did above.

I was confused earlier because I thought we had to prove that $J$ can **only** be expressed as $H/N$ for $N \leq H \leq G$. Maybe this stronger statement is also true; I asked about it here: [Do alternative expressions exist for subgroups of $G/N$, distinct from the correspondence theorem for groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684698/do-alternative-expressions-exist-for-subgroups-of-g-n-distinct-from-the-corre). Regardless, the theorem is true: subgroups $J$ of $G/N$ are always **expressible** as $\beta(J)/N$ for $N \leq \beta(J) \leq G$. Perhaps there are other ways to express $J$ as $W/N$ for $W$ not containing $N$, but $J$ can always be written in the clean form of $H/N$ for $N \leq H \leq G$.